# How to trigger camel route from client request?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have this route:

```
from("timer://test?repeatCount=1").routeId("newRoute")
    .streamCaching()
    .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn()
        .setBody(exchange.getIn()
            .getBody()))
    .marshal()
    .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "This is my body: ${body}")
    .to("activemq:queue://new-queue");
```

When it is in @override configure() it is working on app. startup. But what I want  to do is to call (trigger) that route from Spring Boot RestController.

I have GET endpoint and I want when I call it, the route to do it stuff.

Comment: as stated by the method name, #configure configures the route inside the camel context, it does not "trigger". 
if you want to send a message on that route you should use a producer template.
http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the 'from' clause with something like:

```
from("direct:runGetAllUsers")
```

then in your Spring Rest controller you can invoke the Camel route. There is an example in the [*Camel In Action 2* book](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition) with [source here](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter7/springboot-rest-camel).